# How to solve this recurrence relation: f(n) = 3f(n/2) - 2f(n/4) | f(2) = 5, f(1) = 3

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, recurrence

> f(n) = 3f(n/2) - 2f(n/4)  |  f(2) = 5, f(1) = 3

I have attempted to solve it by letting

> n = 2<sup>k</sup>
>
> f(2<sup>k</sup>) = 3f(2<sup>k-1</sup>) - 2f(2<sup>k-2</sup>)

Then set

> S(k) = f(2<sup>k</sup>)
>
> S(k) = 3*S(k-1) - 2*S(k-2)
>
> let S(k) = x<sup>n</sup>
>
> x<sup>n</sup> = 3x<sup>n-1</sup> - 2x<sup>n-2</sup>  (divide by x<sup>n-2</sup> and
>   rearrange)
>
> x<sup>2</sup> - 3x + 2 = 0
>
> solving for (x-1)(x-2)

---

Here I get a bit stuck as I try to proceed with the following:

> S(k) = c<sub>1</sub>*1<sup>n</sup> + c<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>n</sup>

But cannot go further on my own. Any advice as the substitutions have confused me!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [math.se].

Comment: It belongs to CS no less than to Math

Comment: I think you made a mistake:

x = 3x^(-1) - 2x^(-2) (divide by x^(-2) and rearrange) will be:

x^3 - 3x + 2 = 0 

**NOT**:   x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0 as you done!!!

Comment: Assuming your calculations are correct, you're almost done. Just use your starting params (f(1) and f(2)) to calculate the c1 and c2 constants

Comment: @AndrițchiAlexei, the error is before, it should be 1 or x^0 on the left, the order 2 recurrence has a degree 2 characteristic polynomial, which is correct.

Comment: It should be `S(k) = c1+c2*2^k` or `S(n) = c1+c2*2^n`, do not mix the variables for the running index.

Comment: After S(k)=f(2^k)=c1+c2*2^k => f(n)=c1+c2*n => resolving system: (f(2) = 5, f(1) = 3) => c1+2*c2=5 and c1+c2=3 => c1=1 and c2=2 => f(n)=1+2*n

Comment: @icepack, I'd call it undergraduate CS but not programming, which may fall in a gap between stackoverflow and cstheory.stackexchange.com.